# How to call a value/string from a method into the main method and code will not execute?

Tags: java, string, methods

I am working on a project in school where we need to make a program where you can order a pizza. We were told we could get extra credit if we used different methods in different classes. I've run into a roadblock even my teacher is unable to help me with.

I am testing a method for when your order the crust. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OrderPizzaMethods{

    public String OrderPizzaMethods(){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String crustMenu;
        String crust = "";
        boolean crustChoice = false;
        int topPick = 7;

        crustMenu = "\nWhat type of crust would you like? (No additional charge for crust types)"
                + "\n1) Thin-crust"
                + "\n2) Deep-dish"
                + "\n3) Hand-tossed"
                + "\n4) Done with crust selection"
                + "\n5) Quit"
                + "\nEnter the corresponding number for the option you want.";

        System.out.println(crustMenu);
        while(crustChoice != true){
            topPick = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.println(" ");;

            if (topPick == 1){
                System.out.println("You will have Thin-crust on your pizza!");
                crust = "Thin-crust";
                crustChoice = true;
            }
            else if (topPick == 2){
                System.out.println("You will have Deep-dish crust on your pizza!");
                crust = "Deep-dish crust";
                crustChoice = true;
            }
            else if (topPick == 3){
                System.out.println("You will have Hand-tossed crust on your pizza!");
                crust = "Hand-tossed crust";
                crustChoice = true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice! Please enter a valid choice");
            }
        }
        return crust;
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the program in a test driver class and it doesn't run at all. The JVM runs and then turns off.
Any help would be appreciated! Also is the way I am using return the correct way to return a string to the main method?

Comment: Well what does the "test driver class" look like? How are you running it? Note that you've got a *method* with the same name as your class, which is never a good idea - aside from anything else, it should start with a lower case letter. (It sounds like it should be a class called `PizzaRestaurant` and a method called `order` or something like that...)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens when you run this program because it has no `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Comment: OP said they used a test driver class, which I assume has the PSVM method. And if it doesn't I'm pretty sure java will print a message saying it's missing.

Comment: @mstbaum: You're right about the message. I just tried and got this: `Error: Main method not found in class OrderPizzaMethods, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application`. For all we know, this message is showing up in the console of the OP's IDE but he's not looking at it. Maybe it's minimized or just not standing out. IDEs tend to have rather busy user interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

test the while statement like

while(!crustChoice){...}

Answer (score 0):

Change the method name and then run it. As long as method name is same as class name that method can not return any thing even void, in your case your method and class names are both same so change the name of your method.

Answer (score 0):

In your test class, you need to make sure you are creating an instance of the new class you created for crust selection:

```
    OrderPizzaMethods op = new OrderPizzaMethods();
```

Now, in your test, you should have access to the method you created for crust selection by way of:

```
    String crustChoice = op.OrderPizzaMethods();
```

Since your method returns a String (yes, you are doing it correctly), you'll want to capture that returned string somehow.  I did it above by assigning the string that OrderPizzaMethods() returns to a newly declared String variable called crustChoice which you would then do something with.

Further, I suggest you rename your method OrderPizzaMethods() to something more meaningful and make the first character lowercase.  The typical convention is that class names are capitalized and methods are lowercase to start with and each word after the first capitalized (i.e.

```
Public class OrderPizzaMethods {     

    public String getCrustChoice() {
    ...
    }

    public String getToppings() {
    ...
    }
}
```

You can add more methods in OrderPizzaMethods and would access them the same way as above:

```
    String toppings = op.getToppings();
```

Good luck with your program!  Hope this helps!